# Do I need a dongle for each Rock Band/Guitar Hero game I own, or is one per instrument enough?

Tags: ps3, ps2, rock-band, guitar-hero

Sorry ...Im not a gamer...my gkids are...so I just bought a used ps2/ and ps3 with several games.

the ps2 has rock band, gh van halen, gh aerosmith, gh world tour, along with a kramer striker guiter and gh red octane guitar.

The ps3 has rock band 1 and 2, guitar hero 3 and 5, and guitar hero world tour. The dilemma? no dongles for any of it. My question is do I have to buy dongles for each game? ..or the instruments..?..the dongles are also a little tricky to find. I would so appreciate if someone could clear this up for me as to which dongles I need. Also can I play the ps2 games on ps3...or interchange any of the guitars....Thanks in advance, I appreciate the help. The kids might not play it..but I might....

Comment: You should only need them for the controllers (instruments).

Comment: PS2 games on the PS3 would be a no unless you got the original PS3 when it was released, the next model of the PS3 after the original did not have PS2 Emulation and it's been like that since.

Comment: however even if you have the original model you won't be able to play Guitar Hero games unless you have an adapter *"Although the Guitar Hero games themselves are compatible, the connector mounted on its special controller is not, due to the PS3's lack of ports for PS2 accessories. The guitars can only be used by utilizing third party USB-to-PS2 adapters."* - [Soruce](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_PlayStation_3_backward_compatible_PlayStation_2_and_PlayStation_games)